# Read/Write UITexTField from another class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view with several text fields that I would like to read from the viewController, validate, then call a function in another class in another file to write out the result.

I know I could return the results and write them from the ViewController, but some functions (not shown here) have so many input and output fields that it seems ridiculously complicated to pass them back out.  How do I do this?  Can I do it?  (Or am I just trying to write really bad code?)

This is a simplified version of what I currently have:

MainViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldLength1: UITextField!  
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldLength2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldLength3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldLength4: UITextField!    
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldPerimeter: UITextField!    
    @IBOutlet weak var fieldArea: UITextField!    

    override viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        fieldLength1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        fieldLength2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        fieldLength3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        fieldLength4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)

    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChange() _ textField: UITextField) {
        if isValidEntry(textField: textField) {
            // Here is where I would like to call the function in the other class
            // Something like:
            // MathFunc().perimeter(
            // MathFunc().area
        }
    }

    func isValidEntry() {
        // ensure entries are only numbers and that enough info is present for calculations
    }
}
```

MathFunctions.swift:

```
import Foundation

class MathFunctions {
    func perimeter(l1: Double, l2:Double, l3:Double, l4:Double) -> Double {
        let p = l1 + l2 + l3 + l4    
        // Here is where I would like to write the result to the UITextField
        // Something like:
        // fieldPerimeter.text = p //with some formatting not shown here
    }

    func area(width: Double, length:Double) -> Double {
        let rectArea = width * length 
        // Here is where I would like to write the result to the UITextField
        // Something like:
        // fieldArea.text = rectArea //with some formatting not shown here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it looks to me that `fieldPerimeter` and `fieldArea` should be labels, not text fields. They are output, not input.

Secondly, remember that `area(width:length:)` *returns* the result. Call the function in the view controller and the push the result into the field.

The View Controller is *suppose* to be the thing that pushes values into labels.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but they are fields - another function, for example, might go in reverse, using the area and a side to calculate the other side.

But I think the second part of your answer really clarifies it:  I was just trying to write bad code.  The ViewController should be the one to push the results onto the display, not the function.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Change your MathFunctions to a struct, and change its functions to `static`. Now you can say `MathFunctions.perimeter()` from anywhere.

Comment: or just remove the `MathFunctions` type completely and make the two function free.

Comment: Both of these are good, but that's not what I'm asking.  I want to know how to write to the field from within those functions rather than from the view controller.